# How to run python scripts without specifying their full path

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, path

From the cmd window I have to do this every time I run a script:

```
C:\>cd C:\Users\my name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37

C:\Users\my name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37>python "C:\\Users\\my name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\scripts\\helloWorld.py"
hello world
```

How can I get away from having to paste in all of the paths?

I tried this and a few other things:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2q_b4ugPWk

thanks!

Comment: "I tried this" And what happened then? What's in your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: That youtube link is not relevant to your question about script paths, it is about the path of the python interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the current working directory of your python interpreter.  It basically means the directory you are currently in where you execute the python interpreter, and it relies on that path to look for your script passed in.  If you're inside the script already, you can easily check with `os.getcwd()` method.

In your case, you could have easily done this instead:

```
C:\Users\my name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37>python "scripts\helloWorld.py"
hello world
```

Since your current working directory is `C:\Users\my name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37`, you just need to give it the relative path `scripts\helloWorld.py`.

The current working directory can be easily visualized like this:

```
# cwd.py
import os
print("Current Working Directory is " + os.getcwd())
```

And then when you run the scripts:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents>python cwd.py
Current Working Directory is C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents

C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Some\Other\Path>python cwd.py
Current Working Directory is C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Some\Other\Path
```

Note in any case, if the `cwd.py` was not in the current working directory or in your PATH environment variable, python interpreter would complain it couldn't find the script (because why should it know where your script is stored?)

If you insist in adding the environment variable though, you will need to add the directory to your `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH`... though I have a feeling `\Python37` is already under there.

Comment: the first code block solved the issue mostly, but it would be nice to not have that long path in there (C:\Users\Ben Nachtrieb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37) for visualization purposes.

Comment: This didn't work for me: https://www.hackanons.com/2018/06/how-to-add-python-path-environment.html

Comment: "Doesn't work for me" is hardly helpful.  Describing what actually happens would be better.  Also, ensure you don't have any spaces in between your `;` separated PATH variables.  e.g. `C:\dirA;C:\dirB` would be good, but `C:\dirA; C:\dirB` would not work.  Spaces *within* the variable itself is okay, but no space after `;`.

Comment: While it would be nice to not have a long path typed out every time, I can guarantee littering your PATH environment with unnecessary variables is gonna make your life a lot more difficult.  Imagine you have the same module name `util` in more than one of your PATH directories, which one should Python refer to?

Answer (score 0):

There is a designated directory where you can put your .py scripts if you want to invoke them without specifying the full path.

Setting this up correctly will allow you to run the script simply by invoking the script name (if the .py extension is registered to the interpreter and not an editor).

## Windows

If you have a per-user python installation - which is the installer default - the directory is:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%/python/python39/Scripts
```

Adjust version number as needed.

If you have a system-wide all-user installation, the directory is:

```
%APPDATA%/python/python39/Scripts
```

#### Configuring PATH automatically

The Windows python installer includes an [option to automatically add](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-the-python-executable) this directory (plus the python interpreter path) to your `PATH` environment variable during installation. Select the checkbox at the bottom or use the `PrependPath=1` CLI option.
[image: Python installer dialog showing add-to-path checkbox]

If python is already installed, you can still use the installer to do this. In Control Panel, `Programs and Features`, select the python entry and choose "Uninstall/Change". Then choose "Modify" and select the "Add Python to PATH" checkbox.

Alternatively, if you want to add it manually - search for the `Edit environment variables for your account` in Windows 10. Edit the `PATH` variable in that dialog to add the directory.

## Linux

```
~/.local/bin
```